# info on php function array_walk()

Tags: php, arrays

I was looking for the use-cases of `array_walk()`, so I went to the PHP documentation and view this example.

But I don't understand how the function `test_alter()` modifies  the value of the array.

Can you explain me?

Here's the code:

```
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{ 

    $item1 = "$prefix: $item1";


}

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
}

echo "Before ...:\n";
array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');

array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit');
print_r($fruits);
```

Comment: [`pass by reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) is the keyword here. See the ampersand ->: `function test_alter(` **&** `$item1, $key, $prefix)` ?!

Comment: ok i searched about pass by reference and now i understand!thank you!